# Importing a .dll reference - can't find solution explorer or add reference in VS 1.66

Tags: python, dll, reference, revit-api, autodesk

Going to preface this post with the obligatory, "I'm new to coding and to VS so go easy on me! I'm learning."

With that being said, I'm writing a script for an architectural program called Revit by Autodesk. I'm just trying to run and debug my code within VS instead of the RevitPythonShell. I've located the dll files that I need, but I can't find out where to add the reference. All my google searches show older versions of VS that look entirely different. I can't find the solution explorer or the add reference. Can someone throw me a bone here? Thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched the internet for [visual studio solution explorer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=visual+studio+solution+explorer)?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to add references to the (2) required Revit DLLs - "RevitAPI" and RevitAPIUI" - yes?
I will be a bit verbose here just to be sure it is all covered.  Open the solution explorer window  (menu bar) > View > Solution Explorer.  This will have your project listed with a triangle on the left side.  Select the triangle to expand the parts of your project.  Most likely the 2nd item is "References" - right-click here and select "Add Reference".  In the dialog box that opens, select "Browse" option on the left then the browse button.  Go to the Revit program folder.  Select both DLL files, then select the add button.  This will add both of the DLL files as a reference to your project.
One other important item is to select each DLL files and change their "copy local" setting to False in the properties window (you may need to open this window also - this is also in the View menu).